# How to install clang(LLVM 3.7.0) on windows alongside mingw(gcc 5.1.0)

Tags: c++, windows, gcc, clang

I was trying to install clang to use along side sublime text 3 for sublimelinter and auto complete , but there was an error, i tried to read about the how install clang on windows and several other sources and tried find question on stackoverflow and couldn't find anything to help me. If you can point to another post that might help or provide the steps , it will be great help.

error was -
Installing MSVC integration...
Failed to find MSBuild toolsets directory.
MSVC integration install failed.
Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: Did you install MSBuild and/or tell the install scripts where to find it?

Comment: Microsoft build Tools 2013(12.0.210051.1), using LLVM-3.7.0-win64.exe to install , how tell the installer to where to find it